# Error: Method with does not exist laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I keep on getting this error method with does not exist and I have no idea how to fix it. I saw people who posted similar question like this and it usually the fault of all() but I am not using it. Can anyone help?

controller:

```
public function getPerson(){
     return view('show');
}
public function getInfo($id) {
      $user_info1 = user_info1::where('user_id',$id)->get();
      $data['data'] = DB::table('personal_infos')::with('userinfo1s')->get()->sortByDesc('upload_time'); //error come from this line
      return view('test', compact('user_info1','data'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the function sortByDesc must before the function get();

Comment: I still get the same error after moving the function get() all the way to the end. Error: method with does not exist

Comment: $data['data'] = DB::table('personal_infos')::with('userinfo1s')->sort('uploa‌​d_time','DESC')->get‌​();

Answer (score 0):

sortByDesc is in collection laravel.. use orderby instead

```
$data['data'] = PersonalInfos::with('userinfo1s')->orderby('upload_time')->get();
```

Comment: I got this error instead "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::with()"

Comment: oh ya.. with available in Eloquent only

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by with available with eloquent only

Comment: eager loader 'with' only available when you using Eloquent.. 'with' not exist in normal queries

Comment: But in my model I am using eloquent, does that help? Sorry I am not really sure about the whole eloquent yet, still learning

Comment: this is queries `DB::table('personal_infos')` direct call table name without model.. Eloquent using name of the model ex: PersonalInfo